# Why does Compiled Vite app throw CORS error?

Tags: reactjs, image, cors, vite

Recently I built a React app with Vite IDE. After I compiled it the compiled app does not load if I run the index.html, and it also does not work on a live website, beacuse of CORS error, which is:

`Access to script at 'file:///projectzsuffi/assets/index-3d88cef3.js' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, isolated-app, chrome-extension, chrome, https, chrome-untrusted.`

But it works just fine if I use http-server.

I suspect that it has a problem with the way I import react modules, images and CSS files which is:

```
// App.jsx
import Header from './Header/Header'
// /Header/Header.jsx
import logo from '../assets/examole-logo.png'
import './Header.css'
```

I don't know if this relates to the problem but this is my project file system:
[Image of file tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SX7nx.png)

I mostly suspected the image import, so I tried not to import them but give the path of the images directly in the img tag `<img src='./src/assets/example-logo.png' />` like this. But this meant that I had to change the paths manually before each time I ran `vite build`, and even with the correct paths it did not compiled in the images that were used. So that is obviously not the correct method of doing it. Or my current (default, see below) configs are not configured well.

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react'

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react()],
})
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71618204/16770846)